# Python Community Refractor: Swap letters two at a time

Tags: python

Goal:
Swap two letters at a time in a given string, assuming that the string is even in length.

Summary:
I'm seeking a community refractor to learn if there was a better, more simplistic approach to the goal. The code below works as expected but it's sloppy in my opinion and could be cleaner. You can ignore a majority of the comments, I kept them there to show how I visually solved the problem.

Input: home

Output: ohem

```
ui_list = list(user_input)
master_list = []

# Say Home is the input
# Break each character into a list
## ["H", "O", "M", "E"]
# Take pair count, create nested list for each pair count
# Input the first and second for each pair into new nested list
## [["H", "O"], ["M", "E"]]
# Switch pairs in nested list
## [["O", "H"], ["E", "M"]]


# Divide list by 2, number of pairs
pairs = int(len(user_input) / 2)

# Add new lists into master based on pairs

for i in range(pairs):
    master_list.append([])
    master_list[i].append([])
    master_list[i].append([])

for j in range(2):
    for k in range(2):
        master_list[j][k].append(ui_list.pop(0))

#master_list[0][0].append(ui_list.pop(0))
#master_list[0][1].append(ui_list.pop(0))
#master_list[1][0].append(ui_list.pop(0))
#master_list[1][1].append(ui_list.pop(0))

for l in range(2):
    a, b = master_list[l][0], master_list[l][1]
    a, b = b, a
    master_list[l][0] = a
    master_list[l][1] = b

master_list = [x for l in master_list for x in l] # This is a wasted line of code imho 
master_list = [x for l in master_list for x in l]
print("".join(map(str, master_list)))




#a, b = b, a
#
#c, d = master_list[1][0], master_list[1][1]
#c, d = d, c
#print(master_list[0])
#print(a)
#print(b)
#print(master_list[1])
#print(c)
#print(d)
```

Comment: A "community refractor"? what is that? If you meant you want the community here to refactor your code, then this is off topic.

Comment: Try codereview.stackexchange.com for improvements to working code, after reading their [posting guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and slicing:

```
s = "home"
result = "".join(b+a for a, b in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using slicing, an iterator, and `join`:

```
s = 'home'

print(''.join(s[i:i+2][::-1] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)))
```

Output: `ohem`

*NB. I'm using a double slicing here to get chunks of two and to reverse then. The two slices are to overcome the fact that it is tricky to programmatically access a reverse slice up to the first item.*

Alternatively, slice from the end:

```
print(''.join(s[-i+1:-i-1:-1] for i in range(len(s), 0, -2)))
```